# Several "Error C4430: missing type specifier" error messages

Tags: c++

All the code is supposed to do is create an instance of the class and print the private variable. I've looked through a bunch (over 20) of "Error C4430: missing type specifier" errors on this site but none helped.

Here's the class file ("Number.h"):

```
#ifndef NUMBER_H
#define NUMBER_H

#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Number {
private:
    T myVar;

public:
    Number(T consVariable);
    ~Number();

    void setNumber(T newVar);
    T getNumber();
    bool isEqual(T check);
    bool isBigger(T check);
    bool isSmaller(T check);
};

template <typename T>
Number<T>::Number(T conVar) {
    myVar = conVar;
}

template <typename T>
Number<T>::setNumber(T setVar) {
    myVar = setVar;
}

template <typename T>
Number<T>::getNumber() {
    return myVar;
}

template <typename T>
Number<T>::isEqual(T n) {
    if (myVar == n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template <typename T>
Number<T>::isBigger(T n)
{
    if (myVar >= n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template <typename T>
Number<T>::isSmaller(T n)
    {
    if (myVar <= n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

#endif
```

And the errors:

```
number.h(31): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
number.h(36): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
number.h(44): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
number.h(53): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
number.h(62): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your function definitions other than the constructor and destructor require a return type. For example, consider `setNumber`:

```
template <typename T>
Number<T>::setNumber(T setVar) {
  myVar = setVar;
}
```

This should return `void`:

```
template <typename T>
void Number<T>::setNumber(T setVar) {
  myVar = setVar;
}
```

And then `isEqual` should return `bool`, and so on and so forth.

---

Don't forget to also define your destructor:

```
template <typename T>
Number<T>::~Number() { }
```

In this case, however, you would get away with just using the default destructor.

Comment: *facepalm* Obviously, Thank you (and Andy Prowl)! Only now, I have a new error:

main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Number<int>::~Number<int>(void)" (??1?$Number@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

Answer (score 0):

Your member function *definitions* have no return type. You should specify the same return type you specify in the corresponding *declarations*.

For instance, since you declare `setNumber()` this way:

```
    void setNumber(T newVar);
//  ^^^^
```

Its definition should look this way (notice I added the `void` return type):

```
    template <typename T>
    void Number<T>::setNumber(T setVar) {
//  ^^^^  
//  Don't forget the return type!

        myVar = setVar;
    }
```

This is what your class definition and member function definitions will look like after you do that for every member function:

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Number {
private:
    T myVar;

public:
    Number(T consVariable);
    ~Number();

    void setNumber(T newVar);
    T getNumber();
    bool isEqual(T check);
    bool isBigger(T check);
    bool isSmaller(T check);
};

template <typename T>
Number<T>::Number(T conVar) {
    myVar = conVar;
}

template <typename T>
void Number<T>::setNumber(T setVar) {
    myVar = setVar;
}

template <typename T>
T Number<T>::getNumber() {
    return myVar;
}

template <typename T>
bool Number<T>::isEqual(T n) {
    if (myVar == n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template <typename T>
bool Number<T>::isBigger(T n)
{
    if (myVar >= n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template <typename T>
bool Number<T>::isSmaller(T n)
    {
    if (myVar <= n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```